# Is it possible to host an asp.net MVC in the same folder as asp.net web forms app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, hosting

I have a domain and a hosting account and I'd like to in a folder host an MVC app and in another host asp.net web forms app.

Is it possible?

Comment: "*asp.net classic app*" - do you mean an ASP.NET web forms application, or an actual classic ASP application?  Your terminilogy is throwing me off =)

Comment: I mean Asp.net web forms. Its a 3.5 application

Comment: Cool.  I edited the title and body to reflect that and hopefully avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ASP.NET web forms and ASP.NET MVC applications can reside side-by-side in the same application.  I have that in my current application and it works fine.  You just have to make sure that your classic ASP.NET application paths don't conflict with your ASP.NET MVC routes -- seems that the MVC routing handler wins out.  I've run into that a few times.

[Here's a good article](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc) that walks through hosting web forms and MVC side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, this is most certainly possible. You'll likely want to modify your MVC routes to ignore requests for aspx or axd resources:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can also have different web.config files for each folder. Of course, it depends on the hosting .NET version, if you can use MVC..

Answer (score 0):

You can also have your single hosting host multiple domains, or make a subdomain and host the legacy site there.