# add an ASP.NET MVC project to an existing ASP.NET Web forms application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

How to add an ASP.NET MVC  project to an existing ASP.NET Web forms application. How to call MVC project page from existing website.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx) step-by-step guide on how to do that.

Your question is similar to

[Is it possible to host an asp.net MVC in the same folder as asp.net web forms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009669/is-it-possible-to-host-an-asp-net-mvc-in-the-same-folder-as-asp-net-web-forms-ap)

Answer (score 0):

We were in the exact same situation as you and it's not as bad as you might think.  Thanks to Nuget it's a fairly easy process that you can follow and Dave Paquette describes how to do it in his [blog post](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/12/30/so-you-inherited-an-asp-net-web-forms-application.aspx)

And once you've got Mvc up and running all you need to do to go from one to the other is to redirect to Mvc from webforms:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Controller/Action/")
```

You can also use the Mvc routing system to generate routes from within webforms as well:

```
System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper url = new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper(HttpContexxt.Current.Request.requestContext)
Response.Redirect(url.Action("Action", "Controller"))
```